# save id with the selected answer in php

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to save the result of the the selected answer with the question id. don't know how to pass the id to the DB. here's my code

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('config/manpower_db.php');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question") or die(mysql_error());
$i = '1';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="save_feedback.php" method="post">
<H2> How Will You Rate This Service</H2>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

echo  $row['question'];
  
 // $comp = $row['id'][$i];
  
 // $_SESSION['comp']= $comp;

?>
<br />
<?php


echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='1' >1";
echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='2' >2";
echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='3' >3";
echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='4' >4";
echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='5' >5";


echo'<br/>';
$i++;
}
?>
<br/>

<strong> NOTE:</strong> 1 - Very Poor, 2 - poor, 3 - Okay, 4 - Fair, 5 - Good
<p>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Save to DB

```html
<?php
session_start();

$answer  = $_POST['answer'];

include('config/manpower_db.php');


   
   foreach($hobb as $key=>$val)
{
    $var1=$hobb[$key];
    $var2=$answer[$key];
   
         
            //include ('connect.php');
   //include ('mysql_connect.php');
            $table = "INSERT INTO answer (answer) ".
                     "VALUES ('$var2')";
            mysql_query($table) or die(mysql_error());
            $inserted_fid = mysql_insert_id();
            mysql_close();  
        }

  

echo'<script>alert("Inserted Successfully")</script>'; 

   
?>
```

This works but am trying to save the question id. don't know how to pass that to the database. 
thanks in advance

Comment: That code is open for SQL injection. Also, what have you tried to make it work? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass Id in hidden field

Try this

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('config/manpower_db.php');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question") or die(mysql_error());
$i = '1';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="save_feedback.php" method="post">
<H2> How Will You Rate This Service</H2>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

echo  $row['question'];

  $comp = $row['id'][$i];

 // $_SESSION['comp']= $comp;

?>
<br />
<?php


echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='1' >1";
echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='2' >2";
echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='3' >3";
echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='4' >4";
echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='answer[".$row['id']."]'  value='5' >5";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id'  value=$comp >";


echo'<br/>';
$i++;
}
?>
<br/>

<strong> NOTE:</strong> 1 - Very Poor, 2 - poor, 3 - Okay, 4 - Fair, 5 - Good
<p>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And save data file

```html
<?php
session_start();

$answer  = $_POST['answer'];
$question_id = $_POST['question_id'];

include('config/manpower_db.php');



            foreach($hobb as $key=>$val)
{
    $var1=$hobb[$key];
    $var2=$answer[$key];


            //include ('connect.php');
            //include ('mysql_connect.php');
            $table = "INSERT INTO answer (answer) ".
                     "VALUES ('$var2')";
            mysql_query($table) or die(mysql_error());
            $inserted_fid = mysql_insert_id();
            mysql_close();  
        }



echo'<script>alert("Inserted Successfully")</script>'; 


?>
```

Comment: This worked fine.. Added an array to the hidden field. echo '<input type='hidden' name='comp[".$row['id']."]'  value=$comp >'

Answer (score 1):

pass id in hidden field
if there is only one button then assign your id to value of button

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're assigning a different `<input>` name for each row, meaning each input is essentially a different question. Because of this, each answer will be being sent to the server, for example `$_POST['answer1'];`, `$_POST['answer2'];`, etc.

Remove `[".$row['id']."]` from your inputs and `$answer  = $_POST['answer'];` will result in only the selected input value being stored, and thus entered into the database.

Remember, you're passing the input `value` attribute to the server and referencing it with the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `$row['id']` is a unique number pulled from the `questions` table, so that would be the question id.

So in your save file from this line.

```
$var2=$answer[$key];
```

`$key` is question number, which can be used to save it.